Geometry Nodes: is it possible to select instances by a distance?
I am wondering (and I'm pretty sure that is possible but I just don't knoe how) to select (or group) instances of one collection by a distance between them in geometry nodes.
I have an collection where I have a lot of elements which I then translated so I don't have to animate them by hand and right now they are separated one by one. I would like to group up closest ones by distance between them.
Hope this is possible...
Thanks

Please clarify this a bit.. Do you mean distance from selection? Distance from one another? If you mean from one another, an element could belong to more than one group.. how do you want to decide which? (Proportional Edit has a 'Constant' falloff option)
